# UML and concurrency

Tags: uml

Is there any way (official according to UML 2.0) to have sequence diagrams or activity diagrams in multithreaded environment? Or UML is just "singlethreaded"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UML Activity Diagrams you can fork the flow of control to more than one stream which will be executed simultaneously and you can join them again to unite (maybe before the end of the activity).

Comment: Agreed - my preferred way for showing concurrency.  Have tried using sequence diagrams too, but activity diagrams are always far more successful for communicating with all types of people, business and technical alike.

Answer (score 1):

In sequence diagram, you can define block/operator (i dont know the proper english term) par to denote, that some actions are parallel...almost every relevant diagram has its own way to define parallelism.

Comment: I think you mean, that: In sequence diagram, you can send an asynchronous message to give the meaning that the message caller participant will not wait for the message receiver participant to return. This is modeled to demonstrate threads usually.

Comment: @LordCover, I think he meant to use a [CombinedFragment](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#combined-fragment) with the [par](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#operator-par) operator.

Comment: Yep, I meant the par operator.